# Wrong return value of kendo.parseDate if the year is 1900

Tags: kendo-ui

`Kendo Version: 2014.3.1411`
`Firefox version: 65.0`

Wrong return of datetime after using kendo.parseDate if the year is 1900 converted as a TimeStamp.

Example:

From Controller:

```
Value of DateTime passed as JSON is "1/1/1900 1:00PM" 
`(Timestamp is /Date(-2208970800000)/)`
```

After using `kendo.ParseDate` of the value of Timestamp, `Time became 1:05pm`

It happens if the datatype of the field is time. Value is ok if it is dateTime.

Comment: File Kendo issues to their devs here: https://github.com/telerik/kendo-ui-core/issues

Answer (score 1):

Kendo ui 2014.3.1411 is quite old.

Using the [current version in the dojo](https://dojo.telerik.com/ABisAmeR) this looks okay.

Maybe you should renew your license and/or upgrade the project.

Comment: So the cause of the problem is Kendo UI 2014.3.1411 version ?

Comment: Hi, my workaround here is I used 1901 as default year and the problem solved.